# I'm using Oracle database 11g. I'm using uername "myconnection" (in lowercase) and it says locked

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
C> SQLPUS / AS SYSDBA  
SQL> ALTER USER MYCONNECTION ACCOUNT UNLOCK;  
// It says :  
ERROR at line 1:  
ORA-01918: user 'MYCONNECTION' does not exist
```

I also tried this by putting the username in lowercase but same thing happened again. I want to unlock the account.

Please help me ...

Comment: first check all users https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-administration/oracle-list-users/

Comment: Can you update your question with the login attempt and response from the database? I'd like to see your actual sqlplus command line or connection URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you really created username using lower letter case (which means you enclosed it into double quotes), then you have to do the same always:

```
sqlplus "myconnection"/its_password@database
```

Or, if you want to unlock it, then

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
alter user "myconnection" account unlock;
```

---

Generally speaking, double quotes and mixed case in Oracle mean nothing but trouble. If you can, get rid of them. Forget they even exist.